# Jquery Converting string to Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bit of code where I'm trying to pass the id value of a div to a function, the function then fadeout the first div then fade in the second one. I know that the function takes in objects, because when I try to display the values given to it with $alert() I get [Object object]. When one of the button is clicked it will try to find the id of the div that is visible and then pass it to the fade function, however it finds the id and keeps it in a string, I would need to convert it into an object. Here is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#step1').fadeIn("slow");
  $('#btn1').addClass("btn-primary active");
 
  $('#btn1').click(function() {
   var id = $(".editor .steps").filter(function () { //this gets the value of the active div and saves it into id.
  if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
   return true;
  }
 }).attr('id');
 fade(id, $('#step1')) //tyring to send id and the the step1 to the fade function
  });
  
  $('#btn-step2-video').click(function() {
      fade($('#step1'), $('#step2-video'));
      $('#btn1').addClass("btn-primary");
      $('#btn2').addClass("btn-primary active");
  });

  $('#btn-step2-picture').click(function() {
      fade($('#step1'), $('#step2-picture'));
      btn2.addClass("btn-primary active");
  });
  
  var fade = function(fadeout, fadein){
    $(fadeout).fadeOut("slow");
      $(fadein).fadeIn("slow");
  }
});
</script>

Here is the HTML of the page:

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```html
<div id="steps">
 <button id="btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-step">1</button> 
 <a class="btn-description">Choose type of ad</a>
 <button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-step">2</button>
 <a class="btn">Confirmation &amp; Payment</a>
</div>

<!--
Begining of editor
-->

<div class="editor">

<!-- 
Step 1 of the editor
-->

<div id="step1" class="steps" style="display:none;" >
 <a id="btn-step2-video" style="position:fixed; top: 45%; left: 25%; cursor:pointer"><div class="btn-ad-choice ad-choice">
  <br>
  <p><b>Create a video ad:</b></p>
  <video width="200" height="113" autoplay="autoplay" mute>
     <source src="video/exemple.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
 </div></a>
 
 <a id="btn-step2-picture" style="position:fixed; top: 45%; right: 25%; cursor:pointer"><div class="btn-ad-choice ad-choice">
  <br>
  <p><b>Create a picture ad:</b></p>
  <img src="images/adexemple.jpg" alt="Exemple of a picutre ad" height="113" width="200">
 </div></a>

</div>

<!-- 
Step 2 for video of the editor
-->

<div id="step2-video" class="steps" style="display: none; height:400px; width:100%; background:gray">
 video
</div>

<!-- 
Step 2 for pictures of the editor
-->

<div id="step2-picture" class="steps" style="display: none;">
 picture
</div>

<!--
end of editor
-->
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I edited my javascript to:

```js
$('#btn1').click(function() {
   fade($(".editor .steps:visible"), $('#step1')); //tyring to send id and the the step1 to the fade function
  });
```

suggested by: Arun P Johny
Thanks ;)

Comment: can you share the html sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery object accepts a selector as well, so the only problem I could see is you are not using the [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), you are passing the id and is using it as a [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) so

```
fade('#'+id, $('#step1'))
```

should work.

But you could simplify it by using [visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to

```
$('#btn1').click(function () {
    fade($(".editor .steps:visible"), $('#step1')) //tyring to send id and the the step1 to the fade function
});
```